# Haxe vs Lua in building a heavy traffic web application

Tags: web-applications, lua, architecture, haxe

After spending a couple of hours reading on Lua and Haxe I am still unsure of which would be a better choice to use on the development of a heavy traffic web application.

Which one would give us better server performance if our web-app will be working heavily on the server's side? We also want to keep server's resources at a minimum to avoid suffering heavy lag spikes.

Our first thought was using Java/Spring/Hibernate but we read about how it drains a server's resources fast as its usage grows, so we are trying to figure out an architecture that would allow us to handle heavy traffic and give out a good user experience efficiently on the server's side.

By heavy traffic we are talking of 500+ users at the same time requesting data back and forth from our servers.

Any suggestions outside Lua and Haxe are also appreciated and will be taken into consideration.

Thanks for your time in reading this. =)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Haxe to generate JavaScript with the Node.js type signatures, (here https://github.com/blackdog66/bdog-node). This gives all the great features of Haxe on a very well regarded backend. It's my primary platform.

bd

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Lua as in a self coded WSAPI/Orbit application and it just works nicely. I haven't got a clue about how it scales, but it just works(TM) out-of-the-box with LuaJit, so I guess you can make things blazingly fast.

You can find more information on this [on the Kepler project Github site](https://github.com/keplerproject/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, we will check it out too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Nginx Lua Module](https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module) that can handle ~30k (yes, thirty-thousand) requests per second, [Redis](http://redis.io) and [Nginx Redis Module](https://github.com/agentzh/redis2-nginx-module).

You'll find several Lua web frameworks here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LibrariesAndBindings

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any particular language is a solution to the problem of "draining a server's resources fast as its usage grows."

Does this application exist already?  If so, what is it written in now?  If not, how do you know you will have 500 concurrent users?

I don't think 500+ simultaneous users is that big a deal, and it's likely that it will make little difference which technology you choose, so you should choose one that uses a language (or at least paradigm) you understand well.  If you like Java, go ahead and use it.

I've used Lua (not Haxe); I like it but it does not have the widespread third-party library availability that other languages like Java or C++ or C or Perl or Ruby or Python enjoy, which is a substantial downside for making web apps.

Comment: The application its on its design stage, we do expect to have heavy traffic since we plan to make this site very popular on our local community (it will address a problem our community has been having in regards of coordination and communication) We do have a Java background but we are concerned heavy use will take a toll on the servers and thus we might have to pay extra to our hosting providers (and since we are doing this for charity, we don't have much of a budget) the site will function mainly as a forum to communicate but with several added features not found in a regular forum.